# How can I prevent cartesian product to avoid double counting

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am getting wrong data (cartesian product) when using inner join.

Table t1

```
PurchaseOrder   CostID  Amount
1                1        4
1                2        3
```

Table t2

```
PurchaseOrder   OrderType   ItemId
   1               321        1
   1               321        2
   1               321        3
   1               321        4
   2               128        5
   2               128        6
   3               321        9
```

Required Output

```
 PurchaseOrder  Amount
     1            7
```

My Output

```
 PurchaseOrder  Amount
     1            28
```

I am trying to use inner join to get the output but not getting the right data.

Query:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1
(
PurchaseOrder INT64,
CostID INT64,
Amount INT64
);
INSERT INTO t1
VALUES (1,1,4),(1,2,3);
SELECT *
FROM t1;

CREATE TEMP TABLE t2
(
PurchaseOrder INT64,
OrderType INT64
);
INSERT INTO t2 
VALUES (1,321),(1,321),(1,321),(1,321);
SELECT *
FROM t2;

select t1.PurchaseOrder, sum(amount)
from t1 inner join t2 on t1.PurchaseOrder = t2.PurchaseOrder
where t2.OrderType = 321
group by t1.PurchaseOrder;
```

Comment: why all those dups in the Table2? in order to help you - we need to clearly understand the nature of your data - especially when it looks weird/wrong

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant table 2 has number of Purchase Orders tied to two different order types (321, 128). There is lot of duplicate data in table 2.

Comment: so, how exactly data in Table2 related to data in Table1? as it is right now - i can take a wild guess - but to help you we need to understand it better!

Comment: Why do you have the same value multiple times in `t2`?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant data in table1 and table2 are related to each other by Purchase Order Column (foreign key).  Table 2 contains order type and item ids.

Comment: @shawnt00 i have modified the table2. Though there is a lot of duplicate data in table2.

Comment: if this is design you have in place  - too bad - you need to revisit it - as it is right now it does not make any sense and there is no way to answer your question with some more less reasonable solution! another option possible that you are trying to simplify your real use case and got with this too far toward oversimplification! please revisit your design/question!

Comment: If your join doesn't consider the `ItemId` then you'll still get duplicates. If that corresponds to `CostId` then add it to the join condition.

Comment: Is `OrderType` the same for everything in an order? (We can't tell because you didn't even provide us table names.) Is so then it's in the wrong spot. But also you'd just need to "de-dup" that table before joining to it.

Comment: You can get the required output just by summing the values in table 1, you don’t need to involve table 2 at all. Why do you think you need to join the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to check if some PurchaseOrder has an OrderType 321, that is what you use Table 2 for, to do this check.  But then to sum the amounts, all information is already in Table 1. So I would write the query as follows:

```
select PurchaseOrder, sum(amount)
from t1
where exists
 (select * from t2
  where PurchaseOrder=t1.PurchaseOrder
    and OrderType=321)
group by PurchaseOrder
```

Comment: Hello! It would be helpful for the author if you would share the output of your query (as they did above for theirs).

Comment: My query would return the "required output" that sgsergio had in mind.